# What processes and/or files should I put on Antimalware Service Executable exception list for my python script?

Tags: python, windows, antimalware

I have a python script which uses WMIC commands, one folder (as input) and of course it runs in python.exe.
It creates several input files using WMIC commands (WMIC.exe) and uses them. They all are located in the same folder as the script, which I refer as "Input folder" here.

There's nothing wrong with the script, but Windows Defender's Antimalware Service Executable starts using CPU 10-20% while in the loop.
I have read that adding the used folders and processes in to Windows Defender Security Center exception list the Antimalware Service Executable should ignore them and not use CPU for that.

The problem is that when I add

- Input folder
- WMIC.exe
- python.exe
- cmd.exe
- conhost.exe

to the exception list, the Antimalware Service Executable still runs on 10-20% CPU usage when the loop is running. Should I add something more to the list or why isn't it working like it should be?

Additional information:
[What Task Manager shows when running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnpLL.png)

- Console Window Host called conhost.exe
- Python called python.exe
- Windows Command Processor called cmd.exe
- WMI Commandline Utility called WMIC.exe

All .exe programs I included in the exception list as "process", folder as "folder"